# what is the threading system of flutter

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, internals, isolate

I have coded in dart and flutter for the past 3 months. I have one app in the play store. But I still don't understand how threading system of flutter works.

To make things simple let's take the most basic counter app that you get when you do `flutter create basicapp`.

Question no 1. How many threads are there in that basic app? 
Question no 2. If there are multiple threads when are they created? When it calls `runApp(MyApp())`? 
Question no 3. I know that dart has a concept of isolates. Are isolates the same as threads?

Comment: check [Concurrency in Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

> When the application starts running, there is a single Isolate/Thread
> that we know as the UI thread.

Question 2:

> Generally you are good with a single thread in most applications. But
> in case you want to create a separate Isolate, you can use
> "Isolate.spawn". Provided a link in the end for better understanding.

Question 3:

> Answering simply, Yes.

[Here is a link for better understanding.](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/threading-in-flutter-e5b84c7d8d31)

Cheers!! Hope it helps.

Comment: The link mentioned is dead!